# LibreOffice doesn't start without sudo

Tags: 20.04, permissions, libreoffice

Trying to convert a `.docx` file to PDF and I run into problem.
`sudo libreoffice` is working, but `libreoffice` throws an error:

```
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
LibreOffice 7.5 - Fatal Error: The application cannot be started.
User installation could not be completed.
```

I think this is permissions problem, but I don't know how to change it so that the command will work with `www-data` user.

I'm using LibreOffice 7.5.5.2 50 (Build:2) on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Version 7.5.5.2 suggests that you are using the LibreOffice snap. Is that accurate? What steps are you doing to start the conversion: A command? A menu item?

Comment: Thanks, started working after I added export HOME=/tmp &&  before soffice --convert

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, started working after I added `export HOME=/tmp &&` before `soffice --convert`.

<sup>Solution added here from [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483344/ubuntu-libreoffice-doesnt-start-without-sudo#comment2597295_1483344).</sup>